# Check checkboxex based on values fron json using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a simple html that loads JSON data into a table using Angularjs ng-repeat. One of the fields come as 1 or zero. I want to write a simple AngularJs directive that will show check-boxes as either checked(1) or not (0); and show text success against (1) and failure against(0) rows.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your question exactly? Without using a custom directive you could simply use the built in directive [`ng-checked`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChecked)

Comment: Maybe this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/t7kr8/) I put together will help you. It's not exactly what you're doing but I think it will help get you there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting with angular, you can use `ng-model` inside your `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` to display to decode value inside the loop.

Code:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="o in obj">{{o.id}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="o.checked">
        <div ng-if="o.checked == true">success</div>
        <div ng-if="o.checked != true">fail!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/G9m4H/